# Beamer - list items replace one another

Tags: beamer, lists, vertical-alignment, itemize

In a certain frame, I would like to have a picture at the bottom of the frame and several list items that describe it. So my plan is to divide the frame vertically, put the picture at bottom and the list items on top. However because of room issue, I would like the first item to appear, then be **replaced** by the second item, and so on.

That is, my first slide in that frame should look like:

```
\begin{frame}[t]{System overview}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item item1
            \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \vfill
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{picture.jpg}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

and the second slide:

```
\begin{frame}[t]{System overview}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item item2
            \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \vfill
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{picture.jpg}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

and so on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can simply use overlay specifications on the items. As follows:

```
\begin{frame}[t]{System overview}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<1> item1
      \item<2> item2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
  \vfill
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{picture.jpg}
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

Note that I replaced the `center` environment with `\centering`, it deals better with space. If you want elements to be visible on more than one slide, you can use ranges like `<1-4>` for slides 1 through 4 and `<3->` for from slide 3 onwards.

**Edit:** I misunderstood the quesiton, to keep the items in place you need an `\only` specification. You can renew the `\item` macro to be "overlay-aware" like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\renewcommand<>{\item}[1]{\only#2{\beameroriginal{\item}{#1}}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[t]{System overview}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<1>{item1}
      \item<2>{item2}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
  \vfill
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{picture.jpg}
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that you need the `{}` around the argument to `\item`.

If for some reason you don't want to have to use curly braces to delimit the argument to `\item` or you don't want to renew the item command you can use the action specification like follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[t]{System overview}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<1|only@1> item1
      \item<2|only@2> item2
      \item<3|only@3> item3
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
  \vfill
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{picture.jpg}
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I want the second item to appear **in the same place** as the first item, and so on. Otherwise I don't have room for the picture

Comment: @Elec: see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, it does the trick. But is it possible to define it only locally? (I don't want to change the itemize definition outside that specific frame). Also another issue - is it possible to make the picture "stick" to the bottom of the page? it changes the vertical position as I change slides, depending on the item's number of rows, even though I used \vfill

Comment: @Elec: You can specify `\begin{frame}[b]`, then the whole frame is aligned to bottom instead of center.

Comment: Ok, the updated answer is perfect regarding the items. Do you know how to solve the issue of vertical alignment?

Comment: @tohecz I want to align the picture, not the whole frame

Comment: @Elec: It seems like there is an additional `vfill` after the minipage, perhaps beamer uses it to balance the frame or something, I'm not sure. Adding `vskip 0pt minus `filll` at the end does not make a difference. You can add some additional `\vfill`'s after the one you already have to force it down a little more. Perhaps somebody else knows a way around this... @tohecz's method also forces your items down, which I assume is not what you want.

Comment: @wh1t3 Thanks a lot. I will put a separate question for this.

Answer (score 4):

You need the `\alt` command which works like `\item\alt<1>{item1}{item2}` or nested: `\item\alt<1>{item1}{\alt<2>{item2}{item3}}` etc. Look up the details of this command in the beamer documentation.